# Nginx Giving 403

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, http-status-code-403

I have usecase to have 2 micro services 1st Frontend 2nd Backend
where frontend pod is exposed to outer world and rendering page from backend pod

While access the frontend service i am getting 403 error

below are the yaml for respective pods and config map

frontend pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    run: frontend
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: webpage
      hostPath:
        path: /home/vagrant/html
        type: Directory
    - name: nginx-config-volume
      configMap:
        name: nginx-config
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: frontend
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        subPath: nginx.conf
      - name: webpage
        mountPath: /var/www/html
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
    operator: Exists
```

backend pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    run: backend
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: webpage
      hostPath:
        path: /home/vagrant/html
        type: Directory
  containers:
  - image: php:7.2-fpm
    name: backend
    volumeMounts:
      - name: webpage
        mountPath: /app
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
    operator: Exists
```

Config Map for Nginx

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
    events {
         worker_connections  1024;
      }
    http {
      server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # Set nginx to serve files from the shared volume!
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_pass backend:9000;
        }
      }
    }
```

Services

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
backend      ClusterIP   10.102.90.23    <none>        9000/TCP       60m
frontend     NodePort    10.111.88.172   <none>        80:30054/TCP   9h
```

Comment: does it work outside kubernetes ?

Comment: yes i access it using my local browser it's giving 403

Comment: I saw you mount `/home/vagrant/html`. Is it possible to file system permission? Can you `ls -l /home/vagrant/html`?

Comment: it is able to read html file now but php file are still giving me 404 error. php file is also placed at same location.